# Probability of event appearing at least 2 times

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The average percentage of defective product is 10%. There were released 100 units of this product. What is a probability that there will be at least 2 defective products among them?

I tried to solve this with Bernoulli formula. So, lets say $m$ is a number of defective products. I need to find $P(m \geq 2)$. We can rewrite it like this: $P(m \geq 2) = 1 - P(m < 2) = 1 - P(m=0) - P(m=1)$. So, $P(m=0)= {100\choose 0} (0,9)^{100}$, $P(m=1)= {100\choose 1} (0,1)^{1} (0,9)^{99}$.

So, $P(m \geq 3) = 1 - {100\choose 0} (0,9)^{100} - {100\choose 1} (0,1)^{1} (0,9)^{99} = 1 - 0,00003 - 10 \cdot 0,00003 = 0,99967$

It seems like too high probability. Did i do everything right?

Comment: In expectation, you should have $10$ defective products. With high probability, you'll have around that number, and above $2$.

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right (except that you mistyped $10$ instead in $100$ for the evaluation of ${100\choose 1}$, but the final result is ok).

It's not an unexpected result. If the failure rate is $10\%$, then in $100$ samples we have on average $10$ failures . So, we can guess, it's *very* probable that we have at least $2$ failures.

More in detail, it's a Binomial distribution, the standard deviation is $\sqrt{n p (1-p)}=3$, and it resembles a Gaussian, hence [we can expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) that more than $99.7\%$ of the ocurrences happen in the range $[7,13]$

Comment: i don't see that mistyped

Comment: You wrote $ 1 - 0,00003 - 10 \cdot 0,00003 $ What about that $10$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your computation is correct, I get the same result. Also, it does not seem too high to me, since it is *extremely* unlikely that there is only one or even zero defective products among 100 at such a high deficiency rate.